# automatic dimming keyboard backlight in linux

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, dbus

I'd like to automate keyboard backlight on my Thinkpad X1, like I was used in my old XPS13. At any key press the backlight should switch on, and after a certain idle time (here 30 s) backlight should switch off.
I've written this basic bash script, which works fine although it polls every second through `xprintidle`, and it may drain some battery:

```
#!/bin/bash

function switch {
  echo $1 > /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness
}

while (true); do

  sleep 1
  last=`xprintidle`
  status=`cat /sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight/brightness`
  [ $last -lt 20000 -a $status -lt 2 ] && switch 2 && continue
  [ $last -ge 20000 -a $status -eq 2 ] && switch 1 && continue
  [ $last -ge 30000 -a $status -ge 1 ] && switch 0 && continue

done
```

I was wondering if some non-polling way could be done, such as through systemd or dbus.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can save a process by reading from stdin when you set `status`, i.e. `status=$(</path/to/brightness)`. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, good tip :)

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to run `true` in a subshell - you can ditch the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to optimize the script so that it polls much less often when the light in on. I have also included dbus way to detect status and switch backlight. In order to use qdbus the script must be run as user, and thus writing permission for `/sys/devices/../kbd_backlight/brightness` is required.

```
#!/bin/bash

idletime=30000  # in milliseconds

prepath=/sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:kbd_backlight
sudo chmod a+w $prepath/brightness

function switch {
  echo $1 > $prepath/brightness
  # ALTERNATIVE WITH QDBUS: WORKS BUT SHOWS NOISY OVERLAY ICON
  #qdbus local.org_kde_powerdevil /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/KeyboardBrightnessControl setKeyboardBrightness $1
}

while (true); do

  # BOTH THE FOLLOWING WORK FINE, BUT THE SECOND DONT WORK AS ROOT
  #last=`xprintidle`
  last=`qdbus org.kde.screensaver /ScreenSaver GetSessionIdleTime`

  # BOTH THE FOLLOWING WORK FINE, BUT THE SECOND DONT WORK AS ROOT
  status=`< $prepath/brightness`
  #status=`qdbus org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/KeyboardBrightnessControl keyboardBrightness`

  val=`< $prepath/brightness_hw_changed`

  [ $last -lt $idletime -a $status -lt $val ] && switch $val && sleep ${idletime}e-3 && continue  #SWITCH ON
  [ $last -ge $idletime -a $status -ge $val ] && switch 0                             #SWITCH OFF
  sleep 1

done
```

edit: now the script keeps trace to the brightness chosen by the user with fn key

Comment: Bravo for "solving" your own problem. Good stuff, but join the 90` and use "modern" cmd-substition in the form of `var=$(cmd_with_output)`. These can easily be nested, so it's good to get in the habit of using them. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed I use also $( ) sometimes especially when nesting is needed. Otherwise i find `cmd` cleaner :)